# How to compare contents of pandas data frame cell with previous cell (or other pre-specified distance)

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a Pandas Dataframe containing a column of IDs (1 and 2), and a column of lists of words. I am trying to find the intersection of words between two cells at prespecified positions:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['S1','S2','S1','S2','S1','S2','S1','S2'], 'words': [['apple', 'orange'],
                      ['apple', 'pear'],['melon', 'pineapple'],['apple', 'melon'],['melon', 'fig'],
                      ['plum', 'fig'],['melon', 'apple'],['apple', 'pineapple']]})
```

More specifically, in the above DF I want to compare the words in each cell (which we'll call pos:0) with the words in the previous cell (which we'll call pos: -1), and store the words that co-occur in a new column (called 'matches') in the same row as the cell at pos:0.

For example, the second row contains the words 'apple' and 'pear'. 'Apple' also occurs in the preceding row, but 'pear' does not. So, I would want 'apple' to appear in a column called 'matches' in the second row.

If possible, I would like to be able to set a 'distance' measure which allows me to compare cells at different distances from each other. For example, if the previous row is -1, then the row prior to that would be -2, -3, -4 etc.

I am doing this in Pandas at present but I have no idea if that is sensible. I've no real code to illustrate my efforts thus far because I don't really know where to begin.

Comment: How big is this df?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for create the matches between both lists:

```
s1=df.ID.eq('S1')
groups=s1.cumsum()
df['matches']=( df.groupby(groups) 
                  .transform(lambda x: list(set(x.iat[0]) & set(x.iat[1])))
                  .words
                  .where(~s1) )
print(df)

   ID               words  matches
0  S1     [apple, orange]      NaN
1  S2       [apple, pear]  [apple]
2  S1  [melon, pineapple]      NaN
3  S2      [apple, melon]  [melon]
4  S1        [melon, fig]      NaN
5  S2         [plum, fig]    [fig]
6  S1      [melon, apple]      NaN
7  S2  [apple, pineapple]  [apple]
```

**Detail:**

```
print(groups)

0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    3
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job perfectly. Would you mind explaining what is actually happening though? I have tried looking up the various functions and am getting lost.

Comment: For each group, the co-indexes between the two lists are sought using the method shown here: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129553/obtener-elementos-comunes-de-dos-listas-sin-repecionales

Comment: x.iat [0] and x.iat [1] represent each of the lists in each group. Only the word series obtained with transform is selected. With `Series.where` you set the NaN values

Comment: If you have doubts, could you tell me what part of the code you don't understand?

Comment: Good one with cumsum. That makes it more general. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the column 'words' and shift it:

```
df["w2"]=df.words.shift()                                                                                            

   ID               words                  w2
0  S1     [apple, orange]                 NaN
1  S2       [apple, pear]     [apple, orange]
2  S1  [melon, pineapple]       [apple, pear]
3  S2      [apple, melon]  [melon, pineapple]
4  S1        [melon, fig]      [apple, melon]
5  S2         [plum, fig]        [melon, fig]
6  S1      [melon, apple]         [plum, fig]
7  S2  [apple, pineapple]      [melon, apple]
```

Then calculate distance 1:

```
df["d-1"]=df.apply(lambda r: np.intersect1d(r.words,r.w2), axis=1)                                                   

   ID               words                  w2      d-1
0  S1     [apple, orange]                 NaN       []
1  S2       [apple, pear]     [apple, orange]  [apple]
2  S1  [melon, pineapple]       [apple, pear]       []
3  S2      [apple, melon]  [melon, pineapple]  [melon]
4  S1        [melon, fig]      [apple, melon]  [melon]
5  S2         [plum, fig]        [melon, fig]    [fig]
6  S1      [melon, apple]         [plum, fig]       []
7  S2  [apple, pineapple]      [melon, apple]  [apple]
```

You can shitf 'w2' again, and calculate the distance 2:

```
df.w2.shift()
df["d-2"]=df.apply(lambda r: np.intersect1d(r.words,r.w2), axis=1)
```

and so on.
You can use a loop, if you need all the distances.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use just the **words** column

```py
df['matches']=''
for idx in df.index:
    if idx>0:
        matches = [x for x in (df.loc[idx][1]) if x in (df.loc[idx-1][1])]
        if len(matches)!=0:
            df['matches'][idx]= matches
        else:
            df['matches'][idx] = ""


    ID  words                   matches
0   S1  [apple, orange]     
1   S2  [apple, pear, orange]   [apple, orange]
2   S1  [melon, pineapple]  
3   S2  [apple, melon]          [melon]
4   S1  [melon, fig]            [melon]
5   S2  [plum, fig]             [fig]
6   S1  [melon, apple]  
7   S2  [apple, pineapple]      [apple]
```